# Showing that $\lim_{{x\to 0}}(1+\sin{x})^{\frac{1}{x}} = e$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{{x\to 0}}(1+\sin{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$? I got it from [here](http://planetmath.org/listofcommonlimits). It says L'Hopital, but I can't figure out how to apply it as I don't have a denominator. I also tried to rewrite the limit using trig identities:

$\displaystyle \lim_{{x\to 0}}(1+\sin{x})^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} 2^{\frac{1}{x}}\sin^{\frac{2}{x}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{x}{2}\right) = ?$

Comment: Try using the exponential function. The continuity of the exponential allows you to move the limit into its argument. edit: the answer below is more elegant, but my suggestion gives a clear denominator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $\dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{1}{\sin x}\cdot \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$

Answer (score 4):

If we wish to use L'Hospital's Rule, then we can write

$$(1+\sin x)^{1/x}=e^{\frac{\log(1+\sin x)}{x}}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\sin x)^{1/x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{\left(\frac{\log(1+\sin x)}{x}\right)}\\\\
&e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\log(1+\sin x)}{x}\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\right)}\\\\
&=e
\end{align}$$

Comment: replace e with 10 or log with ln? :P

Comment: @BCLC What are you asking?  Typically, we use $\log (x)$ to denote the natural logarithm.  That is a very common convention.  We use $\log_{b}(x)$ to denote the base $b\ne e$ logarithm.

Comment: [lots of books do that :P](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ItKF3xyci8). idk i think some would find it confusing. i mean why else do we have $\ln(x)$? less characters to type + less confusing

Comment: @BCLC It should be quite clear when one writes $z=e^{\log(z)}$, don't you think?

Comment: @Dr.MV. May I confess that, at my age, I only know one kind of logarithms. You could be interested by the fact that when we were teached about decimal logarithms, the official terminology was (in French) *common* or even *vulgar*.

Comment: @claudeleibovici Claude, that is interesting.  I believe that I learned thr base 10 log before the base $e$ log.

Comment: @Dr.MV. Because you are too young, boy !

Comment: @claudeleibovici Well, not so young.  Just younger than some and older than others.

Answer (score 4):

my answer:

$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\sin x\right)^{1/x}$

$=\lim_{x\to 0}(\left(1+\sin x\right)^{\frac{1}{\sin x}})^{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$

Note: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, so i get

$=(e)^1=e$